# Loading an ajax enabled page into facebox or other lightbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, lightbox

I have a page with a link to a view in another controller and this view has AJAX elements(a nested form). And I wondering whether it's possible to load the page in a facebox or lightbox and still keep the ajax functionality in the page loaded.

The closest thing I have seen is this but it's loads a page that doesn't contain AJAX.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-build-an-unobtrusive-login-system-in-rails/

If this is possible how would you go about implementing this. I am using JQuery if it makes a difference.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I know you can load pages within an iframe element using prettyPhoto (jQuery plugin) [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)